# Firebase queryOrderedByChild queryEqualToValue not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Not having any luck getting my iOS project to query my players friends highscores:

```
private func checkFriendsScores(fbid: Int64)
{
    let users = ref.child("users")
    let fbidQuery = users.queryOrderedByChild("FBID")
    let friendIdNumber = String(fbid)
    let queryFriend = fbidQuery.queryEqualToValue(friendIdNumber)
    queryFriend.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value) { [unowned self](snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot!) in
        self.updateFriendsScores(fbid, data: snapshot)
    }
}
```

That code compiles and runs fine, and other parts of the app are working.  The query should find a friend who has the given FBID, and then fire the updateFriendScores function, but that block never executes.

The data looks like:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "WhiPPS6AbcX6Xp2XQft29JZXR9G3" : {
      "BK035" : [ null, 540, 466, 515, 576, 748, 1019, 765, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
      "FBID" : 10208576492403564
    },
    "d0fT2ge6ALa6QUKFcRApiqjaJd82" : {
      "BK018" : [ null, 646, 646, 646, 646, 646, 646, 646, 646, 646, 646, 646, 646, 646, 646, 646, 646, 646, 646, 646, 646 ],
      "BK035" : [ null, 631, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
      "FBID" : 1652501845074069
    },
    "o67iatcYLRbd2CrgkXGQWZNpmyC3" : {
      "BK018" : [ null, 816, 715, 642, 690, 864, 745, 899, 858, 847, 1045, 1148, 1002, 1119, 833, 1067, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
      "BK035" : [ null, 826, 620, 657, 673, 810, 1090, 804, 932, 931, 1079, 1007, 972, 1098, 1065, 927, 1582, 1195, 1265, 1366, 1548 ],
      "FBID" : 1094051894000026
    },
    "yW5ntKW9pwYvwm2EyvJlGSTzm0M2" : {
      "BK018" : [ null, 763, 457, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
      "BK035" : [ null, 645, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
      "FBID" : 10153916083832933
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are converting an Int64 to a String to perform your query. A string of 12345 is not the same as a value of 12345

The reasoning is sound as queryEqualToValue expects AnyObject, and an Int64 does not conform to AnyObject.

However, converting it to a String makes it a string, not a value, and it's stored in Firebase as a value.

So the solution is either

```
a) Use Int values in general instead of converting to strings
b) Type conversion to an Int. let num = Int(fbid) and then 
       fbidQuery.queryEqualToValue(num)
c) Avoid the issue completely any store/retrieve those numbers as a string in Firebase
```

I'm going with c) as it just makes handling data so much easier in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in your data you are not saving the `FBID` as a `String` so then there is no need for casting it to String when doing the `queryEqualToValue`.

```
private func checkFriendsScores(fbid: Int64){
    let users = ref.child("users")
    let fbidQuery = users.queryOrderedByChild("FBID")
    let queryFriend = fbidQuery.queryEqualToValue(Int(fbid))
    queryFriend.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        let BK035 = snapshot.value!["BK035"] as! NSArray
        self.updateFriendsScores(fbid, data: snapshot)
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: Int64 may not be the best way to handle that var. There are two types of Any 'thing' available in Swift, *Any* which could be a class, stuct or enum or, *AnyObject* which is specifically for class types. queryEqualToValue is expecting AnyObject, and Int64 does not conform to AnyObject as it's not a class, it's a value type. AnyObject can appear to hold Int's but those cases are where behind the scenes AnyObject implicitly converts the Int to a __NSCFNumber. So that needs to be either a String or convert to Int with: let num = Int(fbid) and then:  fbidQuery.queryEqualToValue(num)

Comment: @Jay thanks Jay. Just edited the answer considering your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Problem turned out to be **security rules**.  Here's the rules that worked for me, with a comment showing where I had to add a line.

Since @Jay had a good answer that helps keep the data sane (although it wasn't the root cause of the problem) I've up-voted that as well.

Apologies for not posting the security rules  earlier.  Should have thought of that.

```
// These rules grant write access to a "users" node matching the authenticated
// user's ID from the Firebase auth token; and read access to all "users" nodes
// Since we will look up our friends via their Facebook ID's we need to index on
// that value
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".read": "auth != null",       // <<< Had to add this line
      ".indexOn": "FBID",
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null",       // <<< This was not enough
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that also earlier I had the line:

`".indexOn": "FBID"`

inside the "$uid" scope, and moved it to as shown above after the client side libraries echo'ed out a warning saying the records weren't indexed, and suggesting moving it to the "users" scope.

That warning was what got me looking at the security rules and that lead to the fix.

Thanks for your help all.